# How to remove files in a directory with lots of subdirectories quickly?

Tags: filesystem, rm

I have a directory like this:

```
my-app/
├─ 1/
├─ 2/
├─ .... (a lot of subdirectories)
├─ N/
```

In each subdirectory, there are a LOT of PNG files, like:

```
1
├─ 1.png
├─ 2.png
├─ ....
├─ 100000000.png (not sure)
```

I don't even know how many png files are in each directory because I can't let `ls` to run. Maybe there are too many of them that even `ls` would stuck.

The PNG files are generated by mistake by a script. So I don't need to back up anything. I just want to remove all the PNG files, but keep the directory structure.

I tried to `rm` but it got stuck like the `ls` command.

What should I do?

Comment: Why can't you use the `find` command to get them, and use the option` -delete` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
find my-app/ -mindepth 2 -name '*.png' -delete
```

or (in the bash shell)

```
printf '%s\0' my-app/*/*.png | xargs -r0 rm
```

The former will recurse into sub-subdirectories if present; add `-maxdepth 2` if there are and that's not desirable. The second won't recurse but could be made to if desirable using `globstar`.